# Process.env.PORT vs hardcoded

Tags: javascript, node.js, nuxt.js

I have an issue with process.env.PORT that I can't seem to solve.

I have this code, which does not work as I get the error "The URI is malformed."

```js
async asyncData({ params }) {
    let baseUrl = ''
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        baseUrl = 'https://url.com'
    } else {
        baseUrl = 'http://localhost:' + process.env.PORT || 3000
    }
    const response = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/api/v1/products?popular=true&limit=6`)
    const data = response . data
    return { popularProducts: data.results }
}
```

However, if I go with it works perfectly.

```js
async asyncData({ params }) {
    let baseUrl = ''
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        baseUrl = 'https://url.dk'
    } else {
        baseUrl = 'http://localhost:' + 3001
    }
    const response = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/api/v1/products?popular=true&limit=6`)
    const data = response.data
    return { popularProducts: data.results }
}
```

In the package.json I have set following

```
"dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development PORT=3001 nodemon server/index.js --watch server --fix",
```

Why is this not working for me?

Comment: Think about operator precedence... If you log out the malformed base URL, you'll see the problem.

Comment: `'http://localhost:' + process.env.PORT || 3000` does not what you expect it does, you have to write `'http://localhost:' + (process.env.PORT || 3000)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convert this

```
async asyncData({ params }) {
    let baseUrl = ''
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        baseUrl = 'https://url.com'
    } else {
        baseUrl = 'http://localhost:' + process.env.PORT || 3000
    }
    const response = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/api/v1/products?popular=true&limit=6`)
    const data = response . data
    return { popularProducts: data.results }
}
```

to

```
async asyncData({ params }) {
    let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    let baseUrl = 'http://localhost:' + port;

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        baseUrl = 'https://url.com';
    }

    const response = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/api/v1/products?popular=true&limit=6`)
    const data = response . data
    return { popularProducts: data.results }
}
```

this should work as expected

Comment: This works for me if I set port = process.env.PORT || 3001. Consol.log gives process.env.PORT = undefined. I don't know why that is though.